# Google Map iOS Application Search

Tags: ios, google-maps, search, maps

> Google Place API have different search API for searching place as
>   mentioned in below link:

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search?hl=en

I want exact same result as '**Google Map**' iOS application in my application.

So which API I should use to search and with what parameter?

Currently I am using this **URL** for search :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=xxxx.xx,xxxx.xx&radius=50000&keyword=xxxxx&key=xxx

Answer (score 0):

> Find Search, NearBY Places with Images using Google Place Api
>   Everything related to Google Api Search is given in Demo.

i have created one demo , you can get complete solution , check it.
might be helpful to you.

> [GooglePlacesAPIDemo](https://github.com/mehulparmar4ever/GooglePlacesAPIDemo)

Answer (score 0):

This returns exact result as Google Map. However I have set the type to "ATM" but you can get result for any like restaurant, bars, banks etc.

```
// Call Google Places API as..
NSString * strUrl = [ NSString stringWithFormat : @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search /json?location = %f , %f &radius = % @ &type = atm &sensor = true & name = %@ &key = %@",latitude, longitude, radius.text,UITextField.text, googleAPI_Key ];
```

---

You will get data in JSON format. Parse it according to you.
For latitude and longitude use CLLocationManager to get current location.